# Is there a way to have the same mapping for different methods with different RequestBodies? (PATCH-Request)

Tags: java, spring

I have the following two API-methods:

```
  @PatchMapping("/{id}")
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
  public ResponseEntity<Project> updateProjectInactivity(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody InactivityDTO inactivityDTO) 
  throws ProjectNotFoundException {
    return projectService.updateProjectInactivity(id, inactivityDTO);
  }

  @PatchMapping("/{id}")
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
  public ResponseEntity<Project> updateProjectStatus(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody StatusDTO statusDTO) 
  throws ProjectNotFoundException {
    return projectService.updateProjectStatus(id, statusDTO);
  }
```

The two methods have a different `@RequestBody`, but im currently getting an error because both of them have the same mapping.

Is there a way to have the same mapping for different methods with different RequestBodies? If not, whats the best workaround solution to achieve what i want? I could think of giving them a different `@RequestParameter`, but that would be ugly, because i dont need that parameter. It would be only used to achieve different mapping.

Comment: The idea behind `Patch` is to calculate a patch document upfront that contains instructions that the server should apply atomically (either all or none of them). [RFC 5789](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789#section-2) is pretty self-explanatory and [application/json-patch+json](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902#section-3) is a concrete implementation of that. [application/merge-patch+json](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7386) is a bit different though by assuming certain default rules that should be applied but therefore has a more naturally looking payload.

Comment: The rule of thumb though should be that the endpoint receives a general patch document and not some specific DTO type. Depending on the content-type of the received payload you know whether to apply the steps defined in that payload (json-patch) or some default-rules defined in merge-patch.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the `@PatchMapping("/{id}")` in both methods.

You can have the same url with different request mappings. like below

- @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
- @PatchMapping("/{id}")

You should start using different request path since both the methods are responsible for different actions or changing different sub domain. (As per rest convention)

**for editing the status**

- @PostMapping({"{id}/status"}) - It represents that you are editing the status of an Object.

similarly, you should use different request path for inactivity

Comment: Thats what i said. They have the same mapping. My question was whether theres a way to achieve what i want without haivng to give them a different mapping, because different mapping wouldnt represent what im actually doing.

Comment: And yes, i can have same mapping for different request mappings. But i dont want to break the restful api design we are working with which would be the case if im doing a patchoperation on a delete mapping.

Comment: You should start using different Request path since both the methods are responsible for different actions or changing different sub domain. (As per rest convention)

for editing the status. ->  @PostMapping({"{id}/status"}) - It represents that you are editing the status of an Object.

similarly, you should use request path for inactivity

Comment: `@PostMapping({"{id}/status"})` implicates that you want to create a new status, not change a status of a resource.

Comment: If you want to use @patchMapping, you should have only one java method to update the resource based on the request body.